# How to lesser text description in CGridView in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have that code in my admin.php i.e. view file in my Yii Project.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'topic-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'description:html',  // I want to change this
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Actually `description:html` is showing a lot of text description which is stored in my database.

**So my question is that, I want to print just a single line of description here.**

So I don't know how to accomplish it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although **hett** has given an answer but you can do this also

```
array(
            'name'=>'description',
            'value'=>array($this,'showFewLines')
        ),
```

and then in your **controller create a function**

```
public function showFewLines($data,$row)
{
$allData=$data->description;
return substr($allData, 0, 40);
}
```

Comment: Another option is just to add descriptionBla property, some getSescriptionBla in model and then just put 'descriptionBla' in params. It will be even better -- to hold all model-related code in models.

Comment: @gaRex exactly :) All model related code should be in the model only for simplicity and better understanding. :)

Answer (score 2):

somehow

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'topic-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        array(
            'name'=>'description',
            'value'=>function($data) {
                return substr($data->description, 0, strpos($data->description, '<br>'));
            },
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: maybe you data do not contain <br>?
then use "\n", enable brain please ;)